# Under zsh, looking to use `tr` to search and replace a single character with multiple characters

Tags: shell-script, zsh

I want to replace "Blah: whatever" or "Blah/Whatever" with "Blah--Whatever"

I have this:

```
NEW=`echo ${OLD} | tr '[:/]' '--'`
echo ${NEW}
```

I suppose it's taking the 2 dash characters to mean 1 letter replacement for : or /

How do i tell `tr` to replace : or / with "--"?

using zsh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr` only does character-for-character replacements. Try this:

```
NEW=${OLD//[:\/]/--}
```